# Entity Framework load Parent whit childs to grid

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Hello this my schema edmx

[image]

I try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         JeansEntities db = new JeansEntities();
         GridView1.DataSource = (db.Employes).Include("Address");
         GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And this give me  just the the Employe table data...
I don't understand...

Thanks

Comment: You expect the fields from both tables to show up in the GridView?

Comment: Yes that why I do (db.Employes).Include("Address");

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         using (JeansEntities db = new JeansEntities())
         {
            GridView1.DataSource = db.Employes.Select(p=> new { Id = p.Id, FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, Street = p.Address.Street, Number = p.Address.Number, Country = p.Address.Country, Quarter = p.Address.Quarter }).ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
         }
    }
```